# Laravel 8: How to set default value of all enum values

Tags: php, laravel, enums, migration

I want to assign all default values for `allowed_file_types` column in products table which are all values of enum `FileTypes`. But now I have no way to do that.

Can you help me?

This is my file FileTypes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

/**
 * @method static static OptionOne()
 * @method static static OptionTwo()
 * @method static static OptionThree()
 */
final class FileTypes extends Enum
{
    const JPG =   'jpg';
    const PNG =   'ps';
    const AI = 'ai';
    const PS = 'ps';
    const PDF = 'psd';
    const BMP = 'bmp';
    const IDDD = 'iddd';
}
```

This is my file Migration:

```
 <?php
    
    use App\Enums\FileTypes;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class AddFielsToProductsTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->enum('allowed_file_types', ['jpg', 'png', 'ai', 'ps', 'pdf', 'bmp', 'iddd'])->default(FileTypes::);
                $table->integer('max_file_upload');
                $table->integer('min_jpg_dpi');
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('allowed_file_types');
                $table->dropColumn('max_file_upload');
                $table->dropColumn('min_jpg_dpi');
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can only set the default value to be one of the allowed strings. So you'd need to just pick one to be the default.